# Spring JPA Audit fails with multiple datasources

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

There are many sites explaining how to [set up Spring auditing](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-jpa-auditing-automatically-the-good-stuff).  And I don't intend to rehash all that here.  My problem is that after having Spring Auditing working for a very long time we got a new requirement.

We now have to add a second datasource to read from a different Oracle database. That too seems to work fine.  However very unexpectedly when I added the second datasource the Auditing has stopped working.

The error is the seemingly self explanatory:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "RESTENDPOI0_"."LASTCHANGEDDATE": invalid identifier

The problem seems to be that the LAST_CHANGED_DATE is now missing its underscores.

With Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE it is of course not necessary to declare the datasource (this is picked up from application.yml) nor the entityManager nor the transaction manager.

But when adding a second datasource, in addition to new definitions in application.yml I had to declare two new classes.  One for the PrimaryDataSource (shown below) and one for the secondary (not shown, this is a read only datasource and auditing is not part of it's story).

The obvious answer is that something about manually defining these Beans has broken the EventListener.  But I haven't been able to translate that observation into any sort of solution.

(Apparently) relevant code here:

**AuditModel**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AuditModel implements Serializable {

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "LAST_CHANGED_DATE", nullable = true)
@LastModifiedDate
private Timestamp lastChangedDate;
...
```

**Entity to be Audited**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENDPOINT")
public class Endpoint extends AuditModel {
    private String  endpointName;
    private String  httpVerb;
```

**Primary Data Source**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses={ xxx.scheduler.model.Endpoint.class, xxx.scheduler.repository.EndpointRepository.class} ,
entityManagerFactoryRef = "dashboardEntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "dashboardTransactionManager")

public class PrimaryDataSource {

@Primary
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource dashboardDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dashboardEntityManagerFactory()  {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dashboardDataSource());
    emf.setPersistenceUnitName("schedulerPrimaryPU");
    emf.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    emf.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "xxx.dashboardscheduler.model" });
    return emf;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager dashboardTransactionManager(){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
    dashboardEntityManagerFactory().getObject() );
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
    return vendorAdapter;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced similar issue, and it had nothing to do with audit itself. Somehow the second data source does not pick up field naming convention so the systems maps `lastChangedDate` to `LASTCHANGEDDATE` when it has to be `last_changed_date`. These properties in `dashboardEntityManagerFactory` solved the issue:

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put("hibername.implicit_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
props.put("hibername.physical_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy");
emf.setJpaPropertyMap(props);
```